# Order Images in ListBox DataTemplate Horizontally

Tags: wpf, silverlight, datatemplate

**Preview**

[alt text http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/5466/howtoorderhorizontal.jpg](http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/5466/howtoorderhorizontal.jpg)

On the highlighted item, the images still ordered vertically even I already use `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">`. Am I missing something?

I don't want the images have ListBoxItem behavior (hover/click). I had added `IsEnabled="False"` to the list box, but the images' opacity decreased : ( Do you have any idea how to do this thing?

**Data template**

```
   <!-- FacilityTreeView data template -->
    <telerik:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="FecilityTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Facilities}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Icons}" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Source}" Margin=" 0,0,2,0" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Tooltip}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
    </telerik:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using ItemsPanelTemplate.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
       <Image Source="{Binding Source}" Margin=" 0,0,2,0" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Tooltip}" />
   </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>

<ListBox.ItemsPanelTemplate>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
</ListBox.ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">` as an ItemsPanelTemplate.
[Read more here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemspaneltemplate.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I was trying the solution and I found it's incomplete, **ItemsPanelTemplate** must be inside `<ListBox.ItemsPanel>`

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```